# CTGIN2076E: Exception Running Database method for task validate

Tags: sql-server-2008, middleware, maximo

I'm installing (well trying to) Maximo Asset Management and have already installed MS SQL on a Windows 2008 R2 Server. I have installed Middleware and am now trying to run through the steps to install Maximo 7.5. I have tried Googling this error message however there is only 1 thread on it which has no answer, and the message itself it quite vague and cryptic. Has anyone ever come across this before or could offer any advice on what I should look into to fix it?

Comment: What's the error? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Did you follow the automated database configuration or the manual? Have you double-checked the JDBC URL for your database in IBM\SMP\etc\install.properties?

Comment: You could try installing a Java-based SQL tool, like Oracle's SQL Developer or whatever, and use the libraries that come with Maximo, but I feel like I had to use other ones, to test the JDBC URL and make sure you can run queries against the maximo database.. create a table, query from it, drop it.

Comment: ever find a solution?

Comment: No luck unfortunately.

Comment: In this situation I would check the installation logs for additional information.  Often you'll see a more detailed error in the log pointing to the root cause.